# Meteor template input value undefined

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am creating an app in Meteor with a modal sign-up dialog. For some reason, the value of input text-boxes (username, password and email) is **often** coming out to be undefined. 
Following is the template :

```
    <template name="modalLogin">
         <div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                       <h4 class="modal-title">Login to create your own lists</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="signup-form">
                                <label for="create-user-username">User Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="create-user-username">
                                <label for="create-user-email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" id="create-user-email" >    
                                <label for="create-user-password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="create-user-password">
                               <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Following is the code for the template's event-handler (Removed some code for brevity):

```
Template.modalLogin.events({
    'submit #signup-form': function (evt, template) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        console.log(template);
        var username = template.$('#create-user-username').val(); 
        var email = template.$('#create-user-email').val();
        var password = template.$('#create-user-password').val();
        console.log('username = ' + username);    //undefined
        console.log('email = ' + email);          //undefined
        console.log('password = ' + password);    //undefined  
    }
});
```

I have no idea of why this is happening as there is nothing complicated here. Besides, it does sometimes work which is very confusing.

Comment: can't see anything wrong here. Is it possibly something in the redacted code? How are you adding and removing the modal? Are you closing it at the same time, causing a race condition, where the dom element dissappears before it gets logged?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : simply call jquery for input elements

```
var username = $('#create-user-username').val(); 
var email = $('#create-user-email').val();
var password = $('#create-user-password').val();
```

**Note** : - Please ensure that you have include jquery library before calling this code. Also make sure that you have unique id of input fields through out the DOM structure in your page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! According to official meteor documentation, jquery is already included in meteor and template.$('<selector>') is the recommended way - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$   I have already used it in other places but somehow here it is not working. The ids for the input fields are unique.